# When packaging my Python program, can I remove unused objects from installed packages to minimize binary size?

Tags: python

Say if I use an imaginary package `pip install helloworld` & import it in my script like `import helloWorld`, then I use a function `helloworld.print_hello()`, but have no need for any other objects that might live in `helloworld`, are there any tools that would let me automatically remove those other objects in `helloworld` in my packaged version of my software for the sake of reducing the size of the distributed version of my software?

Comment: If helloworld is an open source project and its license allows it, you could fork a separate project. Rename it and pull out the unneeded stuff.

Comment: I would be very sceptical as *dead code elimination* is probably really hard to do in such "dynamic" languages like python. Look up GraalVM and Javas ahead-of-time compilation to learn about all the shenanigans and crazy stuff they are doing... and that with a language which has a much stronger type-system: In short (although i don't use it) -> there is some "cooperation* needed (not really fully automatic). Imagine a function which samples a random-number, hashes it and imports some other source if and only if the last 4 bits of the hash are 0. PRetty hard to "foresee" this in static analyis.